# invalidate a session from EL

Tags: java, session, jsf, el

How can I invalidate a session using EL?

Comment: why would you want to do that instead of calling a controller method?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using [JBoss EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/elenhancements.html). This EL implementation has the capability to invoke methods directly by `methodname()`. Put [`jboss-el.jar`](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/jboss-releases/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` and add the following to the `web.xml`, assuming you're using Mojarra:

```
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

This way JSF will use this EL implementation to evaluate expressions.

Then you can do in your JSF page:

```
#{session.invalidate()}
```

Needless to say that it's not the best place/practice to do this.

Comment: @BaluC , Then what is the best practice to invalidate a session? I have asked the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619827/how-to-invalidate-session-in-jsf-2-0 Could you pls help?