# How to invalidate session in JSF 2.0?

Tags: session, jsf-2, httpsession, managed-bean, session-scope

What is the best possible way to invalidate session within a JSF 2.0 application? I know JSF itself does not handle session. So far I could find

```
private void reset() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
}
```

1. Is this method correct? Is there a way without touching the
   ServletAPI?
2. Consider a scenario wherein a `@SessionScoped` UserBean handles the
   login-logout of a user. I have this method in the same bean. Now
   when I call the `reset()` method after I'm done with necessary DB
   updates, what will happen to my current session scoped bean? since
   even the bean itself is stored in `HttpSession`?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

> *Firstly, is this method correct? Is there a way without touching the ServletAPI?*

You can use [`ExternalContext#invalidateSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#invalidateSession%28%29) to invalidate the session without the need to grab the Servlet API.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserManager {

    private User current;

    public String logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    // ...

}
```

---

> *what will happen to my current session scoped bean? since even the bean itself is stored in HttpSession?*

It will still be accessible in the current response, but it will not be there anymore in the next request. Thus it's important that a redirect (a new request) is fired after invalidate, otherwise you're still displaying data from the old session. A redirect can be done by adding `faces-redirect=true` to the outcome, as I did in the above example. Another way of sending a redirect is using [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public void logout() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.invalidateSession();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/home.xhtml");
}
```

Its use is however questionable in this context as using a navigation outcome is simpler.

Comment: @BalusC, what's the difference between `ExternalContext#invalidateSession()` and `HttpSession#invalidate()`?

Comment: @Patrick: Functionally, nothing. They both do exactly the same. `ExternalContext#invalidateSession()` calls under the covers `HttpSession#invalidate()` (see also the javadoc link in my answer). Design-technically, the `ExternalContext` approach is better. You should basically strive to have **zero** `javax.servlet.*` imports in any of your JSF related artifacts.

Comment: What about a SSL session? Is it possible to invalidate it? Because I tried unsuccessfully via the suggested method

Answer (score 13):

```
public void logout() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a "normal" redirect I ended up with a login form (where I was redirecting to) which was not working. I ended up doing a JavaScript update of the document href. Using OmniFaces it's looking like this:

```java
if (!Faces.isAjaxRequest()) {
  throw new FacesException("Ajax request is required");
}
// ... Do logout from your security manager here (we use Shiro)
Ajax.oncomplete("document.location.href='" + url + "'");
```

Answer (score -1):

Frontend code is:

```
<h:form>
<h:commandLink action="#{userManager.logout()}">
       <span>Close your session</span>
</h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Backend code is:

```
public String logout() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    return "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";  
}
```