# To invalidate session when user close browser by using servlet

Tags: java, session, servlets

I invalidate session when user click logout button. But when user close browser, how do I invalidate session by using servlet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562411/how-to-invalidate-the-session-on-browser-close-in-the-jsf may helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch close page event as described [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event) and send `ajax` request like when user make logout

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use either onunload (for IE) or onbeforeunload (for firefox) events of *javascript* to redirect your page to the url of the servlet (same as for Logout button) that invalidates the session.

```
<script>
    function logout(){
       window.location.href='sessionInvalidatorServlet';
    }
</script

<body onunload="logout()">
.........
....
```