# Redirection takes place , but url is not updated accordingly

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i have used navigation rules , to navigate from one page to another in jsf . But the problem is the url is not getting updated though i used  in faces-config page .

code snippet is below:

faces-config.xml :

```
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>faces/layout.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/faces/layout.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/faces/logout.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

source.java

```
public String Logout() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();    
    isLogged = false;
    session = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    if(session != null)
    {
        session.setAttribute("username", "");  
        session.invalidate();
    }
    return "logout";
}
```

sample.xhtml :

```
<p:splitButton value="#{loginBean.getUsername()}" icon="ui-icon-person">
    <p:menuitem value="Logout" icon="ui-icon-close" action="#{source.Logout()}" ajax="false"/>
</p:splitButton>
```

any help is always appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: add: return "logout?faces-redirect=true"

Comment: Try only `<navigation-rule> <navigation-case> ... </navigation-case> </navigation-rule>` without <from-view-id> and <display-name>.

Comment: There's no need to grab the servlet API as you're doing to invalidate the session. Have a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619827/how-to-invalidate-session-in-jsf-2-0).